# How to remove double quote use onkeyup attr inline?

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

I tried

```
<input type="text" name="first_name" 
  onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[\-\'\.\,\/\`\:\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\=\;\|\{\}\[\]\<\>\?]/g,'')">
```

it works for almost all special chars, but when I add a double-quote filter like

```
 <input type="text" name="first_name" in first  
      onkeyup="value=value.replace(/[\"\-\'\.\,\/\`\:\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\=\;\|\{\}\[\]\<\>\?]/g,'')">
```

it seems to not allow to do like that. I want to custom remove the mark I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put your code in an external function instead of placing it inline. It's just that the `"` interferes with the html attributes' `"` and break the code.

```js
document.querySelector(".no-special-chars").addEventListener("keyup", function(){
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[\"\-\'\.\,\/\`\:\~\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\=\;\|\{\}\[\]\<\>\?]/g,'');
});//keyup()
```

```html
<input class="no-special-chars" type="text" name="first_name" />
```

Comment: @hchang909 you're welcome.